# Pick the 3rd and 4th octet in an IP and assign it a hostname

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access I am trying to sort IPs by their 3rd and 4th octet, and then have them sorted out as [IpAddress] and [HostName] in their respective column. The third octet will be linked to a server rack. E.g. 1,22, or 121 and the 4th octet will be linked to its location in the rack. E.g. s1, s22, or s121. So the IP will be sorted from a list and a query to build the HostName off of an IP. How could/should I go about doing this. I am not very experienced with MS access. I have tried useing an iif statement, but I am unable to get the desired results. I would like for the HostName to follow this nomenclature: 121s1. Thanks for all the help.

```
SELECT IIf(query1.Ipaddress Like '*.*.3.#', "1003s'#'", 22) AS HostName
FROM Query1;
```

This is the line that I am trying to use. However, it only will produce an output with the quotes around 1003a'#'. If I do not have the "" around it it will return "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression IIf(query1.Ipaddress Like '*.*.3.#', 1003a'#', 22). With the quotes it puts exactly what is in the quotes (1003a'#'). 22 is just a place holder so I can an answer back in access. Maybe this will help with what I am asking for.

Comment: How is the IP Address stored? 1.1.1.0? If so, split it based on the `.` into 4 columns. That way it will be easier to deal with.

Comment: Please list the code you have used to acheive your undesired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @WEI_DBA suggests in a comment to the question, consider changing the way you store the IP addresses. Instead of a single string

```
IpAddress
----------
10.0.121.1
10.0.12.34
```

you could store them as four separate integers

```
IpOctet1  IpOctet2  IpOctet3  IpOctet4
--------  --------  --------  --------
      10         0       121         1
      10         0        12        34
```

Then you could simply derive the HostName as

```vbs
IpOctet3 & "s" & IpOctet4
```

and if you wanted the old representation for display purposes you could just use

```vbs
IpOctet1 & "." & IpOctet2 & "." & IpOctet3 & "." & IpOctet4
```

After adding the 4 new `Integer` columns to your table you could populate them using VBA code like this:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub SplitIpAddresses()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE IpAddress IS NOT NULL", dbOpenDynaset)
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        Dim octets As Variant
        octets = Split(rst!IpAddress, ".")
        rst.Edit
        rst!IpOctet1 = octets(0)
        rst!IpOctet2 = octets(1)
        rst!IpOctet3 = octets(2)
        rst!IpOctet4 = octets(3)
        rst.Update
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Changing how the Ip is stored (albeit a great idea) kind of defeats the purpose of what I am trying to accomplish. And the 3rd octet only refers to a server rack and not what it actually is e.g. 121 could be rack 903. I am trying to figure out a way to have the 3rd octet represent something and the 4th be pulled from the Ip and be placed at the back of the HostName.

Comment: No I wouldn't say that it "defeats the purpose", I would argue that it *advances* the purpose. If storing the IP address as a string makes your life harder and storing it as four separate (integer) octets makes it easier then one might reasonably consider that to be a "good thing".

Comment: I agree that it could/would be a good thing and possibly easier, but what I want to accomplish is an IF statement (or any other) that will use the 3rd octet as an 'unique identifier' and the 4th octet as a 'wildcard' to be pulled and inserted at the back of the HostName. I do not know if this is possible, if it is not then I will resort to this method.

Comment: Ok, I have given up on the idea above and have moved on to trying to separate the ip into 4 columns. Do you know a way this can be done in a none manual way? I tried using a  SPLIT command and I was unable( perhaps I am not good at this). Do you have any suggestions of how this can be accomplished without having to manually separate 300 ips individually? I tried using this:  `qdf1 = " Select [792].IpAddress, Split ( *.*.*.* , ".",4)" & _
        " From 792; "`

Comment: I have entered that into the VB and I keep getting "Run-time error '3265' item not found in this collection." 
  `Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [792].IpAddress FROM 792 WHERE IpAddress IS NOT NULL", dbOpenDynaset)
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        Dim octets As Variant
        octets = Split(rst!IpAddress, ".")
        rst.Edit
        rst!IpOctet1 = octets(0) **this is the "error"**
        rst!IpOctet2 = octets(1)
        rst!IpOctet3 = octets(2)
        rst!IpOctet4 = octets(3)`
all of your code was put in. I also created integer columns with IpOctet1-4.

Comment: @arand0m9uy - You're only selecting the [IpAddress] column into the Recordset. You need to `SELECT * FROM ...` so the other columns will be in the Recordset and available to be updated.

Comment: You are awesome ( probably don't get tired of that one!). Thank you for all you help and wisdom.

Comment: Is there a reason why an IF statement would not work inside of that sub?
`If IpOctet3 = 3 Then
        HostName = "6003s' & IpOctet4 & '"
    End If`
HostName has been declared

Comment: Yes, something like that *could* work, but it is generally not a good idea to hard-wire such mappings into application code. It would be better to maintain a separate mapping table with rows that link, for example,  [IpOctet3] values to [HostNamePrefix] values.

Comment: Do you know a way I could add this statement and have it work? I would like to not add more table if possible, but if that is the best/only option could you help with that as I am clueless.

Comment: I figured it out. 
`Str = " SELECT [792].IpAddress, [792].IpOctet3, [792].IpOctet4, IIf(IpOctet3=3,'6003a' & IpOctet4 & '') as HostName" & _
          " FROM 792; "
Set qdf = cdb.CreateQueryDef("Host")
qdf.SQL = Str` This made it work perfectly.